# How to make a drop down from link on click in html and css

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to make a dropdown menu using HTML & CSS only. What I have is a set of links/buttons on my page (anyone will do). When I will click on them I want a 3 level drop down menu to show up. So all the links will have this feature, when I click on them.

I know how to do this using jquery, but I am wondering how to do this using HTML & CSS only.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Pure CSS Dropdown](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu)

You can use :hover to draw list items or another div.

Answer (score 0):

try my simple lazy way ,

```
<style>
.container{
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 300px;
    background: yellow;
}

.container:hover{
overflow:visible;
    height: 300px;
}

.main ul li{
    display:none;
}
</style>
    <div class="container">
<a class="main" href="javascript:void(0)">menu</a>

<ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub menu4</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87VLS/3/

Comment: Its a good one, but how to add another sub-sub-menu item, coz i wanted it to be 3 - levels :)